# Re-execute model hook and rerender in Ember js

Tags: ember.js

I have in my Ember App, a route displaying a list of offers;
the model is loaded by jquery ajax (I don't use Ember-data):

```
    Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: App.restAPIpath + '/offers/', 
        headers: {
            "tokens": localStorage.tokens
        },
        async: false
    }).then(function(res) {
        data = res.offers;
    });
    return data;
```

The offers are shown in the template using a datatable and in each row there's a delete button that sends an ajax delete request to the server and correctly deletes the right offer:

```
{{#view App.dataTableView}}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Deadline</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Deadline</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        {{#each offer in model}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{offer.createdAt}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{#link-to 'eng.offers.edit' offer}}{{offer.name}}{{/link-to}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{offer.deadline}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{offer.optionDuration}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="form-button-red" {{action "deleteOffer" offer}}>Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
{{/view}}
```

but then I need to update the model (and refresh the view?) because if not the deleted offer is still shown until you refresh the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend switching your ajax to async, you'll block the router from doing other important things.  You should be able to accomplish the same results doing this:

```
return Ember.$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: App.restAPIpath + '/offers/', 
    headers: {
        "tokens": localStorage.tokens
    },
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.offers;
});
```

Then I'd do something like this for your delete (I'm going to guess a bit of your code) in your controller's `delete` action:

```
actions:{
  delete: function(item){
    var self = this;
    Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: App.restAPIpath + '/delete/' + item.get('id'), 
        headers: {
            "tokens": localStorage.tokens
        },
    }).then(function(){
      //manually remove the item from your collection
      self.removeObject(item);
    });
  }
}
```

BTW I think delete is a reserved key word and jslint and some minimizers are total haters, so you might do something like `deleteItem`

Comment: Yes the code for deletion is like the one you wrote, but that doesn't work for me: it says that 'undefined is not a function';  instead I tried self.get('model').removeObject(item) that seems to go further, but now i get  the error: cannot read 'parentNode' of null, coming from the function at line 26815 of Ember 1.5.1

Comment: I created a similar app, it looks to be mostly working (I made some small hacks to make it work in the jsbin, (such as removing the app.tableview, go ahead and add it).  Hopefully we can track down the difference and find where the issue lies.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fugimeme/1/edit

Comment: Ok, you're right, it works also for me without the datatable; I've added the datatable also in your js bin, so now you can see the famous error 'cannot read property parentNode of null':  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fugimeme/2/edit?css,js,output